# Simple area and angles of squares and triangels

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a question APPARANTLY tested on primary 4 and I am in Sec 2,wondering how to do this question....None of my classmates also could finish the question.

Question:

ABCD and BFGE are squares.AE and BE meet at the intersection point where E is midway of DC.In square BFGE,it have 4 congruent triangles and a shape as shown in the figure below.Answer(Teacher challenged us:NO FIGURE SHOWN BELOW,DRAW YOURSELF)

(a)The ratio of ABCD to the smallest square

(b)Determine if the area of BCE equals to the area of the smallest square.

(c)Find the value of angle AEB.If possible,avoid using trigonometry.

First,the figure doesn't seem to be enough description to draw.Second,no measurements are given at all,which is literally impossible to use trigonometry.

I thought this question is a crap question given by teacher as impossible as a joke.I would love to see how would u have done it.

Here is what I have drawn for this:
[image: Figure from Instagram]

Comment: The angle $\angle AEB$ can take any value from $45°$ to $53.1301°$, without considering what "4 congruent triangles" means. Without that it's impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I agree.It seems more impossible to solve the question,but I seemed to manage to draw,except I can't visually place it here.(If you would like to see the picture,search in instagram @itzliddatone) (Apologies for looking like instgram advertising but I have no intention of trying to attract followers) (EDIT:Just unprivated my account)

Comment: @kennytm: I don't follow your argument. The figure appears pretty completely determined by the description, and everything else follows from that. Do you see any way how the figure could have looked different in an essential way? How would it look to obtain those $45°$ you claim?

Comment: @MvG: Sorry that comment was made before the figure is posted. And OP says the square is BFEG not BFGE which means the figure would look like this instead: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHZE.png

Comment: @kennytm Apologies for the square naming error.It have been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your figure, we can determine all required quantities.

[image: Figure]

1. The congruent triangles are right triangles, and their legs have a ratio of $1:2$. The former is because one such triangle is in the corner of the square, while the latter is due to the fact that $E$ is the midpoint of $CD$. Since all questions are invariant to scaling, you can choose your scale of length arbitrarily, e.g. in such a way that the short legs of the congruent triangles have length $1$. Then you'd have $AB=BC=CD=DA=2$ and $EC=CK=KL=LM=MC=1$ is half that length, so the small square has half the edge langth and a quarter the area of the square $ABCD$.
2. Well, the area of a right triangle is half the product of its leg lengths, in this case $1$ and $2$ as stated above. So yes, they are of equal area.
3. I don't know how to avoid trigonometry here. The triangle $ABE$ has one side of length $2$ and two sides of length $\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt5$ according to Pythagoras' theorem. By the cosine law, you have $$\angle AEB=\arccos\frac{5+5-4}{2\cdot\sqrt5\cdot\sqrt5}=\arccos\frac35\approx53.13°$$ but that angle seems not to be a rational multiple of $\pi$ so I see no easy way to obtain that angle exactly without using trigonometric functions.

Comment: Very good and well done.I actually didn't know that M is the midway of B and C which is surprising.After u draw,I actually drew to scale,assuming AB is any length.So apparently it is suddenly true that BM:BC is indeed 1:2.Perfect answer.I also agree that it's impossible to avoid trigonometry